# get single index number of a duplicate element in a list

Tags: python, list, loops, arraylist, indexing

I want to turn this "RqaEzty" into this "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy". it basically prints out a letter as many times as the index of it is.
I created the following method, but it has one mistake.
Every time a letter occurs twice or more in the input my output is wrong, because my code takes the same index of the letter appearing for the first time as for the same letter appearing the second time

E.g. "ZpglnRxqenU" should be

**"Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnnnnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu"**
but I get:

**"Z-Pp-Ggg-Llll-Nnnnn-Rrrrrr-Xxxxxxx-Qqqqqqqq-Eeeeeeeee-Nnnnn-Uuuuuuuuuuu"**
because my code takes the same index for the first "n" as for the second "n"

```
 def accum(s):
        x = list(s)
        s = ""
        for y in x:
            amount = 1 + (x.index(y))
            word = y * amount
            s += word.capitalize() + "-"
        s = s.rstrip('-')
        print(s)
```

my idea is to implement an if function into the "for loop" to control wether a letter occurs more than once and if yes to put out the index of the second (or third or fourth...) letter.

My question:
how do I put out the index of a duplicate as a single value?

Comment: There's no need to convert `s` to a list, python strings are iterable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for the index every time, you could iterate over the indexes themselves:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    y = x[i];
    amount = 1 + i
    word = y * amount
    s += word.capitalize() + "-"
```

Comment: An even better option is to use the `enumerate` builtin, which decorates the value with its index, so `for i, y in enumerate(x):` will give you all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter variable instead of (x.index(y))

```
def accum(s):
        x = list(s)
        s = ""
        i=1 #change happens here
        for y in x:
            word = y * i #change happens here
            s += word.capitalize() + "-"
            i+1
        s = s.rstrip('-')
        print(s)
```

It will solve the error

Answer (score 0):

If you need a value that increases each step, you can use `enumerate()`.

Then it will work.

```
def accum(s):
    x = list(s)
    s = ""
    for idx, y in enumerate(x):
        amount = 1 + idx
        word = y * amount
        s += word.capitalize() + "-"
    s = s.rstrip('-')
    print(s)
```